# Displaying existing Claim Value in SelfAssertedAttributeProvider at Azure B2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm building a Sign-in-flow for a login where the user may need to re-consent the terms-of-use.

I'm collecting the required version via the Restful Provider and can see that the claim contains the expected string.

I'm also able to display the checkbox.

What I can't figure out is **how to display the version-claim that I collected in the previous orchestration step**.

Or to rephrase: I just want to display a simple string I collected before.
The format doesn't matter, as I can restructure the form via JavaScript.

**Claim Definitions**

```
  <ClaimType Id="consentVersion">
    <DisplayName>consentVersion</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</DataType>
    <AdminHelpText>The new version the user has to accept.</AdminHelpText>
  </ClaimType>
  <ClaimType Id="termsOfUseCheckBox">
    <DisplayName></DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserInputType>CheckboxMultiSelect</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
      <Enumeration Text=" I agree" Value="True" SelectByDefault="false" />
    </Restriction>
  </ClaimType>
```

**ClaimProvider TechnicalProfile**

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Input-ToU-SignIn">
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted ToU</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
        Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.updatedtou</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="termsOfUseCheckBox" DefaultValue="False" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="consentVersion" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="termsOfUseCheckBox" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use displayclaims or outputClaims to display a something on screen.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#display-claims

Combine with InputClaims to prepopulate the claim on screen.

Comment: Thank you - don't know why I missed this paragraph in the docs. Working like a charm now.